# Unable to assign a LUIS azure accounts to an application due to permission denied

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-language-understanding, azure-sdk-.net

To [assign a LUIS azure accounts to an application](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515), if I use a token from [here](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true), I can see the post is executed successfully, but if I use the Azure Active Directory app to generete a token, the API post returns an error.

{ "error": { "code": "BadArgument", "message": "You don't have permissions to perform this action" } }

To replicate the issue, you can use the [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) to generate a token and then use the [Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services LUIS Authoring API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Authoring/) to assign a LUIS azure account to a LUIS application.  Another way to replicate the problem is to use the test console [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515/console) to simulate the issue (use your own data, of course).

Maybe I'm missing some permission that I need to grant, but I can't find a way to allow permissions for [this LUIS API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515).  Any suggestions are appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
In the documentation, it says to get an Azure Resource Manager token from this [website](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true), so am I supposed to use this somehow for programmatic purposes (to avoid logging into the LUIS portal)?  It's confusing since the doc says the token expires, so it doesn't sound right to me.  Or is my approach above to use the Active Directory library to generate a token on-the-fly the correct strategy?

[image]

Comment: are you the owner or collaborator for the LUIS app?

Comment: I'm the owner for the LUIS app

Comment: Do you experience the same for any other app which you own as well?also, what value are you passing for the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key?

Comment: Yes, it's happening with all my other apps as well, using LUIS (Authoring) subscription key, if I use the token from [here](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true) then it works as expected, but if I generate a token from azure AD app then I get this error { "error": { "code": "BadArgument", "message": "You don't have permissions to perform this action" } }

Comment: Just to make sure that you have entered the correct credentials,in the API call, the Authorization:Bearer {token}  /  Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: authoring key. Since you are generating the token for an Azure AD app, that Azure AD app has to have access to the authoring key.

Comment: How did you solve this
I am facing the same issue

Comment: @gd vigneshwar go to your subscription and assign role to your ARM app as contributor

Answer (score 1):

Go to your subscription and assign Contributor role to your ARM app as contributor